# trigger explanation needed - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

What it mean? Is the below query is correct

```
CREATE TRIGGER FIRST1 ON temp_bids 
After update as 
insert into temp_bids1(`BID_ID`,
  `LoanId`,
  `Bid_Size`,
  `Interest_Rate` ,
  `Up_to_me`) SELECT `BID_ID`,
  `LoanId`,
  `Bid_Size`,
  `Interest_Rate` ,
  `Up_to_me` FROM Updated;
```

Comment: Do you have a table named `Updated`?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what @HABO said, NO, it is not valid. You have an INSERTED and a DELETED table, but not an UPDATED.  Updates are thought of as a DELETE and INSERT.

Comment: and I think its mysql code not sql server, I dont know maybe there is a updated table in mysql

Comment: It's tagged SQL-Server.

Comment: @Steve - The backticks are MySQL though.

Comment: @MartinSmith Even if the tag is wrong, there is no UPDATED table in MySQL, they use NEW and OLD for thier tables as oppesed to INSERTED and DELETED. An update would have an OLD and a NEW, but no UPDATED.